# JBoss Inconsistent stack height 2 != 1

Tags: java, jboss, resteasy, verifyerror

I'm successfully able to deploy the RESTEasy application on JBoss instance but when I'm trying to invoke the service it is throwing me an Inconsistent stack height exceptions on Red Hat Santiago. However the application tested on Windows machine and works fine.

Below is the stack trace:

`ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/ani].[com.org.ani.JaxRsActivator]] (http-/0.0.0.0:8081-4) JBWEB000236: Servle
t.service() for servlet com.org.ani.JaxRsActivator threw exception: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: com.google.common.collect.ComputationException: java.l
ang.VerifyError: (class: com/org/ani/CallLogger$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy, method: parse signature: (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;) Inconsistent stack height
 2 != 1
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:264) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.5.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleInvokerException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:209) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.5.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:557) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.5.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:524) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.5.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:126) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.5.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.5.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.5.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.5.Final.jar:]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final.jar:1.0.2.Final]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.5.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServlet30Dispatcher.service(HttpServlet30Dispatcher.java) [async-http-servlet-3.0-2.3.5.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:920) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
Caused by: com.google.common.collect.ComputationException: java.lang.VerifyError: (class: com/org/ani/CallLogger$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy, method: parse signature: (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;) Inconsistent stack height 2 != 1
        at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingMapAdapter.get(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:400)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider.getClientProxy(ClientProxyProvider.java:102) [weld-core-1.1.10.Final.jar:2012-10-12 10:00]
        at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:603) [weld-core-1.1.10.Final.jar:2012-10-12 10:00]
        at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:635) [weld-core-1.1.10.Final.jar:2012-10-12 10:00]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.cdi.CdiConstructorInjector.construct(CdiConstructorInjector.java:65) [resteasy-cdi-2.3.5.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.cdi.CdiConstructorInjector.construct(CdiConstructorInjector.java:70) [resteasy-cdi-2.3.5.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.resourcefactory.POJOResourceFactory.createResource(POJOResourceFactory.java:43) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.5.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:210) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.5.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:542) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.5.Final.jar:]
        ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: (class: com/firstdata/ani/CallLogger$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy, method: parse signature: (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;) Inconsistent stack height 2 != 1
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2585) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2885) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:350) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
        at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$16.work(SecureReflections.java:344) [weld-core-1.1.10.Final.jar:2012-10-12 10:00]
        at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:52) [weld-core-1.1.10.Final.jar:2012-10-12 10:00]
        at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInstantiation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:173) [weld-core-1.1.10.Final.jar:2012-10-12 10:00]
        at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.newInstance(SecureReflections.java:341) [weld-core-1.1.10.Final.jar:2012-10-12 10:00]
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyFactory.create(ProxyFactory.java:242) [weld-core-1.1.10.Final.jar:2012-10-12 10:00]
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyFactory.create(ClientProxyFactory.java:105) [weld-core-1.1.10.Final.jar:2012-10-12 10:00]
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider.createClientProxy(ClientProxyProvider.java:87) [weld-core-1.1.10.Final.jar:2012-10-12 10:00]
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider.access$000(ClientProxyProvider.java:43) [weld-core-1.1.10.Final.jar:2012-10-12 10:00]
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider$1.apply(ClientProxyProvider.java:53) [weld-core-1.1.10.Final.jar:2012-10-12 10:00]
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider$1.apply(ClientProxyProvider.java:46) [weld-core-1.1.10.Final.jar:2012-10-12 10:00]
        at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingValueReference.compute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:358)
        at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingSegment.compute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:184)
        at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingSegment.getOrCompute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:153)
        at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap.getOrCompute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:69)
        at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingMapAdapter.get(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:396)
        ... 29 more`

Comment: Looks like you compiled the code in a higher version than what its deployed to.

Comment: Thanks but I'm using the same Java version.

Comment: It appears to be a bug to me, I suggest you try using a newer version of the library (and jboss, and Java)

Answer (score 0):

As Peter mentioned looks like it's an issue with the JVM on the specific instance, I have downloaded the latest JVM on another Unix box and tried to run the application. It worked.

Thanks everyone for your help.